# Class and Object level variables in Swift 2.0

Tags: python, swift, python-3.x, swift2

I have started learning Swift recently and noticed that class declaration is sort of similar to pythons, the only thing which scratches my mind is are class and object level variables working the same in both of the languages?

Like in python:

```
class foo:
    # class level variable, changing this changes bar
    # for all the instances of the class
    bar = 0

    def __init__(self):
        # object level variable, modifying only changes baz of current object
        self.baz = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description of what your Python code does, this is the translation to Swift:

```
class Foo {
    static var bar = 0

    var baz : Int

    init() {
        baz = 1
    }
}
```

Class-level/static variables have to be annotated with the `static` keyword, as do class-level/static methods.

Comment: Also how exactly does the self keyword work then? In python you always have to explicitly say self if referring to the current instance, so what difference it would be between self.baz and baz?

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij None, `self.baz` is equal to just `baz` (except `baz` is already a local variable). `self` is optional except in the case of a closure capturing self, it's needed there, XCode will yell at you to put a `self` there so that's no problem.